# ORA-13605: The specified task or object does not exist for the current user

Tags: oracle, performance

I have successfully generated AWR report.

However, I found the following line at the end of the report.

```
ADDM Task ADDM:4076550766_1_609
Error encountered in special section 99995 ORA-13605: The specified task or object does not exist for the curren t user. 
Continuing to Next Section...
Back to Top
End of Report
```

I do not understand why this error is coming up even though the report was successfully generated.

Comment: As what user are you running the AWR report?

Comment: @sandman i am running AWR report as an admin user

Comment: So it depends what privileges this user has.  If you run the report as SYSTEM or a user with DBA privileges then you should not get that error.  It depends how your DBA has set up that admin user in OEM (I presume).

Comment: @sandman okay so basically this error is related to configuration of privileges? which doesn't make any difference to the results of AWR. Right?

Comment: It does make a difference as it will only run the sections it has privs on, as you can see from your missing section.